# How to program conditional Values across two dataframes in R?

Tags: r, subset

I have a couple of data frames that I am attempting to use the values from one data frame to populate the cells of a column in a separate data frame.
They are as follows:

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = c("Doug", "Michele", "Steve", "John", "Pete", "David"))
df1$B <- 0
df2 <- data.frame(A = c("Doug", "Steve", "John"), B = c(1,1,0))
```

And the result that I am looking for is:

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = c("Doug", "Michele", "Steve", "John", "Pete", "David"), B = c(1,0,1,0,0,0))
```

I tried the following approach, but only Doug has a 1 value while the others are 0.

```
df1$B[(df1$A == df2$A & df2$B == 1)] <- 1
```

When attempting an approach with %in%, Doug has a 1 value but John does as well when Steve should be the one to receive the 1.

```
 df1$B[(df1$A %in% df2$A & df2$B == 1)] <- 1
```

Am I missing something here that would resolve this issue?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option with `data.table` would be to join `on` the 'A' column and assign the 'B' from the second dataset (`i.B`) to 'B' in first data

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2, B := i.B, on = .(A)]
```

-output

```
df1
#          A B
#1:    Doug 1
#2: Michele 0
#3:   Steve 1
#4:    John 0
#5:    Pete 0
#6:   David 0
```